# Terminate tomcat if port is already occupied

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application which runs on tomcat and reports its status to another monitoring application (this monitoring application monitors several other processes in the system).

If the app gets deployed successfully in tomcat, the monitoring application shows that the app is live and operational.

But, if tomcat fails to listen on the port which is configured in `Connector` element  in `serer.xml`, still the app gets deployed, so it is shown as live in the monitoring application. But, users cannot actually access the web application since the web server is not listening on the configured port.

Is there a way I can configure tomcat so that it will terminate (or at least not deploy the webapps) if it fails to listen on the server port?

Comment: Why not make the monitoring program try to send requests on the relevant port once the application deployed ? putting something like a mock ```alive.html``` on the deployed application ?

Comment: Why not use HTTP probes to detect the "liveness" of the application instead of having the application phone-home to the monitoring system?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein your approach is good, but the monitoring application is not under my control. It is developed by a separate team and it has it's own API to communicate with it. This is the first time it is monitoring a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/xkr47/9088839) which might help you to implement a logic that binds to Tomcat's `init` event and checks for status of its components (according to the comments in the gist, you might already find a maven artifact which do the same).

Create a lifecycle listener, something like `ConnectorListener` and make it implement the `LifeCycleListener` interface. Then put the code from the gist into the overrided `lifeCycleEvent` method (you should make some adjustments to make it fit).

Then add it to your `web.xml` under `<engine>` tags.

Comment: I cannot understand where the code given in the gist should be placed. Can you please explain?

Comment: I've made the answer a bit more detailed.

Comment: I didn't find a way to add a lifeccycle listener in the app itself. As per the documentation, (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Lifecycle_Listeners) lifecycle listeners should be added in the context.xml and placed in the `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory. I couldn't find any reference to the `<engine>` tag anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some script in `{tomcat_setup}/bin/startup.sh` file.

Add below script after line contains `EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh`.

```
parent=`dirname "$PRGDIR"`
file="$parent"/conf/server.xml
host=`hostname`
#get ports from server.xml
for i in `grep -o "<Connector port=\".*\"" "$file" | cut -d\" -f2`;
do
  #check port is listening
  ret=`cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/"$host"/"$i"`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Tomcat is already working!"
        exit 1
  fi
done
```